# add data of an index to another index of same array in php

Tags: php

hello I using laravel and magento DB to get data, I want to make tree like structure of following data. Initially when I got data is like this.

```
Array
(
   [parent] => Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 5740
                [name] => Sports
                [parent_id] => 5739
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 6057
                [name] => Football
                [parent_id] => 5740
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [entity_id] => 6058
                [name] => American
                [parent_id] => 6057
            )

    )

)
```

and I want the above data in following format to use in my application.

```
Array
(
  [parent] => Array
    (
            [0] => Array
            (
                    [entity_id] => 5740
                    [name] => Sports
                    [parent_id] => 5739
                    [child] => Array
                    (
                            [entity_id] => 6057
                            [name] => Football
                            [parent_id] => 5740
                            [child]=> Array
                            (
                                    [entity_id] => 6058
                                    [name] => American
                                    [parent_id] => 6057
                            )
                    )
            )

    )

)
```

can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: You're probably going to need to post your model relationships and the code your using to actually get the data to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution handling unordered hierarchies

```
function hierarchize($data){
    $parentLess = [];
    $map = [];

    foreach($data['parent'] as &$entity){
        $id = $entity['entity_id'];
        $parentId = $entity['parent_id'];

        $map[$id] = &$entity;

        if(isset($map[$parentId])){
            $map[$parentId]['child'][] = &$entity;
        }else{
            $parentLess[$parentId][] = &$entity;
        }

        if(isset($parentLess[$id])){
            $entity['child'] = &$parentLess[$id];
            unset($parentLess[$id]);
        }
    }

    return $parentLess;
}
```

https://eval.in/145508